# Handling multiple resolutions of illustration/artwork in Android

Tags: android, material-design

I have a SVG with some empty state artwork I made in Inkscape and would like to export it as a PNG to use in my app.

How do I know which sizes to export the PNG as?

Do I just export at 1x, 1.33x, 2x, 2.66x to handle different densities, then let Android handle image scaling to fit in the `CardView` `ImageView` container?

For example, in the [Material Design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/empty-states.html#empty-states-avoiding-completely-empty-states), there is some placeholder artwork:

[image]

I read through https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html but it's still not clear what to do with these types of artwork.

The "image asset" mode in Android Studio also only supports Launcher/Notification/Action bar icons, but I need guidance on scaling for artwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with PNG images you will have to use different scales to support every screen density, and going with the same scales as icon sets seems reasonable to me, if this is about keeping the right proportions.

If your concern is to efficiently fill the screen you may also want to consider using SVG directly (API 21+), to be able to resize it smoothly. It also have the benefit of not bundling big PNGs in your app. See here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html